# How do I transfer an existing remote ssh key from the server to my local desktop?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ssh, webserver

I tried similar answers to similar questions but the answer doesn't seem to work in my case.

I'm using a **local** desktop and running inside the terminal to log into a **remote** server.  I'm using **localuser@remoteIP** where 'localuser' and the name of the user on the server are the same.

Now, I know **the server has an ssh key for my non-privileged user** as I was able to log in before. But now I'm on a different machine and it won't let me. The error message given is:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

That is what led me to believe that I need the **server key for 'localuser'** on my new computer. I know there is a way to copy the remote key to this box but I don't know how to do it. I'm using a VPS with **Ubuntu 18.04** on DigitalOcean in case that matters. I've tried `ssh -vvv` and it doesn't do anything.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The server would normally only have the *public* key; you would need to copy the *private* key from the client machine from which you logged in before

Comment: Generate a new keypair with ssh-keygen or puttygen and give the public key to the serveradministrator. You can have more the one public key on the server for your account.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I don't have access to the original client machine. But now that I know I have to go the other way, I should be able to figure it out by creating a new key. I'll just have to enable password login in sshd on the server so I can transfer the transfer the key. Thanks.